# Div does not appear to contain (enclose) its span element children

Tags: html, css

The inner `div` does not appear to contain (enclose) its `span` element children when inspected using dev tools. From what I've learned, a `div` automatically inherits the size (height and width) of the content inside that `div`, but in this case it's not happening. Why not? Is it something to do with the `span` elements?

```css
:root {
  --side_length: 200px;
  --dot_ratio: 0.15;
}

.dice {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  perspective: 1000px;
  perspective-origin: 50% 100%;
}

.dot {
  background: #FFF;
  height: calc(var(--side_length) * var(--dot_ratio));
  width: calc(var(--side_length) * var(--dot_ratio));
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dot1 {
  position: absolute;
}

.dot2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc((var(--side_length) - (var(--side_length) * var(--dot_ratio))) * 0.5);
}

.dot3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(var(--side_length) - (var(--side_length) * var(--dot_ratio)));
}

.dot4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc((var(--side_length) - (var(--side_length) * var(--dot_ratio))) * 0.5);
}

.dot5 {
  /* (side_length - height) / 2 */
  position: absolute;
  top: calc((var(--side_length) - (var(--side_length) * var(--dot_ratio))) * 0.5);
  left: calc((var(--side_length) - (var(--side_length) * var(--dot_ratio))) * 0.5);
}

.dot6 {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc((var(--side_length) - (var(--side_length) * var(--dot_ratio))) * 0.5);
  left: calc(var(--side_length) - (var(--side_length) * var(--dot_ratio)));
}

.dot7 {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(var(--side_length) - (var(--side_length) * var(--dot_ratio)));
}

.dot8 {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(var(--side_length) - (var(--side_length) * var(--dot_ratio)));
  left: calc((var(--side_length) - (var(--side_length) * var(--dot_ratio))) * 0.5);
}

.dot9 {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(var(--side_length) - (var(--side_length) * var(--dot_ratio)));
  left: calc(var(--side_length) - (var(--side_length) * var(--dot_ratio)));
}

.face {
  height: var(--side_length);
  width: var(--side_length);
  margin: 0;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="face">
  <div style="position: absolute;">
    <span class="dot dot1"></span>
    <span class="dot dot2"></span>
    <span class="dot dot3"></span>
    <span class="dot dot4"></span>
    <span class="dot dot5"></span>
    <span class="dot dot6"></span>
    <span class="dot dot7"></span>
    <span class="dot dot8"></span>
    <span class="dot dot9"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[codepen.io](https://codepen.io/Esiarpze/pen/RwMZbmx)

Comment: What do you expect in output?

Comment: @Shrey The second div should contain the span tags, but in my case it's showing height and width of the second div as 0 in the inspection dev tools.

Comment: No. In Dev Tools height and width of `span`  is **30px**

Comment: It does contain the span elements (in the sense of the DOM) but as they are all set to display absolute they don't contribute anything to the height and width of their parent.

Comment: @Shrey I know, I'm talking about the second div which encloses the span tags.

Comment: **absolutely** positioned elements don't behave as **block** level elements and do not flow after each other like normal a `div` does. If you want to *inherit* height and width just add that property like `width: inherit;` and `height: inherit;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

In particular, it says:

`position: absolute` -- The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout.

If you change `<span>` to `<p>`, you will see the same problem. Put a coloured border on the inner div to see where it appears.

Using `position: absolute` to position each element individually is a very complicated way to approach this problem.

I would suggest using flexbox (you could also use gridbox).

Add a container class to the inner div. I added a red border to it so that you can see that the inner container `div` expands to surround the `<span>` children, i.e. the white circles.

There are many ways to position the circles.

For example:

```css
:root {
    --side_length: 200px;
    --dot_ratio: 0.15;
}

.dice {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    perspective: 1000px;
    perspective-origin: 50% 100%;
}

.dot {
    background: #FFF;
    height: calc(var(--side_length) * var(--dot_ratio));
    width: calc(var(--side_length) * var(--dot_ratio));
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 17px;  
}

.sub-face {
    position: absolute;
}

.face {
    height: var(--side_length);
    width: var(--side_length);
    margin: 0;
    background: #000;
}

.container {
  border: solid 3px red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="face">
  <div class="container">
    <span class = "dot"></span>
    <span class = "dot"></span>
    <span class = "dot"></span>
    <span class = "dot"></span>
    <span class = "dot"></span>
    <span class = "dot"></span>
    <span class = "dot"></span>
    <span class = "dot"></span>
    <span class = "dot"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I've considered using flexbox/grid. But I want to know why this doesn't work.

Comment: I was just reading about it, yes, it creates a stacking structure, so I reckon what happens is that all the span tags end one upon the other on the z-axis, in other words the ``div`` tag doesn't necessarily "contain" the span tags.

Comment: This depends on what you mean by 'contain'. The spans are the children of the div.

Comment: @AHaworth Indeed they're the children of the div but not in the same axis, so in a sense it doesn't _"contain"_ it . By contain I mean from a dimensional perspective.